# ASP.Net MVC C# retrieving the last post of a parent child child table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a typical forum app, using nested tables:

**Forum => Topic => Post(s)**

I'm trying to use LINQ to populate a ViewModel to show the last poster for a post, in a topic, within a Forum - however, when I run the query, I get the error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'centreforum.Models.Post LastOrDefault[Post](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[centreforum.Models.Post]) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

I know it's on this line within the query:

`LastPost = f.Topics.FirstOrDefault().Posts.LastOrDefault().Author`

My controller is:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         var forum = db.Fora.Include(x => x.Topics)
             .Select(f => new ForumViewModel
             {
                 ForumId =f.ForumId,
                 Title=f.Title,
                 Description=f.Description,
                 Topics=f.Topics.Count(),
                 Posts=f.Topics.FirstOrDefault().Posts.Count(),
                 LastPost = f.Topics.FirstOrDefault().Posts.LastOrDefault().Author 
             }
            ).ToList();

        return View(forum);
    }
```

My Models are:

```
namespace centreforum.Models
{
public class Forum
{
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string DateOfPost { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string DateOfPost { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
}
```

...and my ViewModel is:

```
namespace centreforum.Models
{
public class ForumViewModel
{
        public int ForumId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Topics { get; set; }
        public int Posts { get; set; }
        public string LastPost { get; set; }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me to find the last post within a topic, within my query please?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LastPost = f.Topics.FirstOrDefault().Posts.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedAt).LastOrDefault().Author
```

I think that if you order your Posts by a given criteria, for example a createdat, it should work as expected.